# DD4T ViewModel Error "An item with the same key has already been added" Tridion Sites 96

Tags: dd4t, sites-9.6

we are upgraded CM & CD to Tridion Sites 9.6 on Dev Environment.

if we are trying to access websites its working as expected except Few pages.

Few pages (having default.aspx under root folder) are getting 500 Internal Server Error. its not happening for all the default pages but few pages only getting Error. can you please help us to fix the issue.

Please find attached stracktrace for same error.

at DD4T.ViewModels.ViewModelFactory.ProcessViewModel(IViewModel viewModel, Type type, IContextModel contextModel)
at DD4T.ViewModels.ViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel(Type type, IModel modelData, IContextModel contextModel)
at DD4T.ViewModels.ViewModelFactory.BuildViewModelByAttribute[T](IModel modelData, IContextModel contextModel)
at DD4T.ViewModels.ViewModelFactory.BuildViewModel(IModel modelData, IContextModel contextModel)
at DD4T.Mvc.Controllers.ModelControllerBase.PageModel(String url)
at Kone.Web.Controllers.PageController.PageModel(String url) in C:\xxxxx\Web\Controllers\PageController.cs:line 155
at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.b__2()

Comment: Do you add any additional fields in the TBB - if you do, are you confirming the schema field hasn't already been populated in the CMS? Either way, I'd suggest sticking DEBUG on and look through the detail - that will, at least show which field.